# Show notification then after 5 seconds navigation to other page

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to create a notification. After 5 seconds the notification should vanish then it goes to another page.

```
export class AppComponent  {
name = 'Angular 5';
constructor(private router: Router) {
  var notify = new Notification('', {body: 'test'});
  setTimeout(notify.close.bind(notify), 5000);
  this.router.navigate(['/page1']);
  }
}
```

However it navigates to the other page immediately; I can't see the notification.

[Stackblize demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/routing-example-39j3x8)

Comment: try this ` setTimeout(()=>this.router.navigate(['/page1']), 5000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, you want to show the notification and on close of it redirect to a different page.

Try this:

```
 export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  constructor(private router: Router) {
      var notify = new Notification('', {body: 'This is a notification'});
      notify.onclose = (
          () => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['/page1']);
          }, 5000);
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

Stackblitz Editor: https://stackblitz.com/edit/routing-example-x8hbhm

Stackblitz App url: https://routing-example-x8hbhm.stackblitz.io

You also might want to check if the notification permission was granted or not.

Example from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

```
if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // If it's okay let's create a notification
    var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
  }

  // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
  else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
    Notification.requestPermission().then(function (permission) {
      // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
      if (permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I want the notification completely vanished then redirect to the other page. Now they seem even the notification has not closed it already goes to another page.

Comment: Sure, I have modified my answer and the stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class AppComponent  {
name = 'Angular 5';

    constructor(private router: Router) {
      var notify = new Notification('', {body: 'test'});
      setTimeout(()=> {
         notify.close.bind(notify);
         this.router.navigate(['/page1']);
      }, 5000);
      }

}
```

Comment: 5 seconds works out, but I still can't see the popup. The size is 0?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Can you highlight the notification? For example, set the border color as red so I can see it. Now I can't see it.

Comment: notification depends on what library you are using, but i have answered your question.

Comment: It's standard js notification. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

Comment: you have to check wheter you have permission

Comment: In stackblitz it will not work, as there is no permission to use notification. open browser devtools console you will see the error there.